# how to validation fields for TabularInline in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-modeladmin

I create a BaseInlineFormSet like this:

```
class ProductPictureRequiredFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data["image"] == None:
            raise ValidationError("error")
        return self.cleaned_data["image"]
```

and use this formset in my TabularInline class:

```
class ProductPictureAdminInline(SortableTabularInline):
    formset = ProductPictureRequiredFormSet
    fields = ("title", "image", "is_default", "order", "created_by", "created_at", "updated_at")
    readonly_fields = ("created_by", "created_at", "updated_at")
    model = ProductPicture
    extra = 3
```

but i got this error:

```
BaseFormSet.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default_order_direction'
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue,

changed `forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet` to `adminsortable2.admin.CustomInlineFormSet`
Since `SortableTabularInline` inhertits from `SortableInlineAdminMixin`

```
class SortableTabularInline(SortableInlineAdminMixin, admin.TabularInline):
    template = 'adminsortable2/edit_inline/tabular-django-{0}.{1}.html'.format(*DJANGO_VERSION)
```

which uses `CustomInlineFormSet` as formset

```
class CustomInlineFormSet(CustomInlineFormSetMixin, BaseInlineFormSet):
    pass

class SortableInlineAdminMixin:
    formset = CustomInlineFormSet
    def __init__(self, parent_model, admin_site):
        if parent_model in admin_site._registry:
            assert isinstance(admin_site._registry[parent_model], SortableAdminBase), \
                "{} must inherit from SortableAdminBase since {} inherits from SortableInlineAdminMixin.".format(
                    admin_site._registry[parent_model], self.__class__.__name__
```

so try changing to

```
class ProductPictureRequiredFormSet(adminsortable2.admin.CustomInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data["image"] == None:
            raise ValidationError("error")
        return self.cleaned_data["image"]
```

and it might resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I did the same thing before and it worked @armstrove